# Redirecting back to actual page what they were viewing before login

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If my user is redirected to a login page, how to make it so that, after they log in, they get redirected to the -original- destination page (the one they first clicked on)?

Answer (score 8):

Pass the originally requested URL as request parameter on the redirect to the login page.

```
String from = request.getRequestURI();

if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
    from += "?" + request.getQueryString();
}

response.sendRedirect("login.jsp?from=" + URLEncoder.encode(from, "UTF-8"));
```

In `login.jsp`, pass it to the login form submit target as a hidden input field.

```xml
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.from)}" />
```

*(note: `fn:escapeXml()` prevents you from XSS when redisplaying user-controlled data in HTML)*

In the login action, check if it is there and then handle accordingly.

```
String from = request.getParameter("from");

if (from != null && !from.isEmpty()) {
    response.sendRedirect(from);
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
}
```

Comment: I am getting a undefined error for fn:escapeXml I have the jstl lib included in my project as well as the functions library referenced inside the head of my page

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. What is the advantage of this approach (query string parameter + hidden input field) over the approach where we just directly store the previous requested URI into current session. In order to maintain the logged-in status, we already rely upon maintenance of user session, so in this case here we can also utilize session

Comment: @torez233: remembering in session won't work when user opens different webpages in multiple browser windows/tabs and then logs in through first opened window/tab. User would incorrectly be redirected to the webpage opened in the last opened window/tab.

Comment: @BalusC thanks again for your answer. I do see another minor issue here: what if the query string is something like "foo=bar&bar=baz"? (notice the "&"). In the code snippet above, user will be redirected to **login.jsp?from=<previous-uri>?foo=bar&bar=baz**. Browser would think this query string actually consists of two parameters, one is **from** and the other one is **bar**. This way, when user submit the forms, the part belongs to the second parameter in the original query string will be lost.
So I think the query string part also need to be url-encoded, to escape characters like "&"

Comment: @torez233: you're right, answer has been fixed