# How to redirect to the simple authorization page in doFilter() (KerberosAuthFilter)?

Tags: spring, spring-security, servlet-filters, response.redirect, spring-security-kerberos

There was a problem with redirecting to the ordinary authorization page (through the login and password form), if the user could not log in through Kerberos. In the `doFilter()` method of the `KerberosAuthFilter` class, I do a redirect if the header turned out to be empty or did not satisfy the requirements (code below), but instead of redirecting from the `somehost:9090/` to `somehost:9090/login` page, I get an endless output of the string "redirect".

Please help me how to fix this. Сode below

P.S. Authorization through Kerberos works and authorization through the login and password form, too, the only problem is that I can’t configure a redirect to the `/login`

```
// part of SecurityConfig
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/file/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/company/*/portals").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/portal/logo/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**", "/ticket/otId/*").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "ARTICLE_EDITOR", "NEWS_EDITOR", "CATALOG_EDITOR", "CATALOG_OBSERVER")
                .antMatchers("/support**").hasRole("SUPPORT")
                .antMatchers("/redirect**").authenticated()

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_URL)
                .usernameParameter(LOGIN_PARAM)
                .passwordParameter(PASSWORD_PARAM)
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(portalAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL)
                .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_PAGE_URL)
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeParameter(REMEMBER_ME_PARAM)
                .rememberMeCookieName(REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_NAME)
                .tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1))
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(kerberosAuthFilter(),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
        return new SpnegoEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosAuthFilter kerberosAuthFilter() {
        KerberosAuthFilter filter = new KerberosAuthFilter();

        try {
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            filter.setFailureHandler(kerberosAuthenticationFailureHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("FAILED TO SET AuthenticationManager on SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter\n", e);
        }

        return filter;
    }
```

```
// doFilter() in KerberosAuthFilter
//the KerberosAuthFilter class is the same as the custom SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter, //except for the end of the doFilter () method
  @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (skipIfAlreadyAuthenticated) {
            Authentication existingAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            if (existingAuth != null && existingAuth.isAuthenticated()
                    && (existingAuth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) == false) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
        }

        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (header != null && (header.startsWith("Negotiate ") || header.startsWith("Kerberos "))) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Received Negotiate Header for request " + request.getRequestURL() + ": " + header);
            }
            byte[] base64Token = header.substring(header.indexOf(" ") + 1).getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] kerberosTicket = Base64.decode(base64Token);
            KerberosServiceRequestToken authenticationRequest = new KerberosServiceRequestToken(kerberosTicket);
            authenticationRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
            Authentication authentication;
            try {
                authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequest);
            } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                logger.warn("Negotiate Header was invalid: " + header, e);
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                if (failureHandler != null) {
                    failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, e);
                } else {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                    response.flushBuffer();
                }
                return;
            }
            sessionStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            if (successHandler != null) {
                successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/login.html");
            System.out.println("redirect");
            return;
        }

    }
```

Log:[image]

In browser result after redirect:
[image]

Comment: in resolve of this question me help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819501/servlet-filter-runs-in-infinite-redirect-loop-when-user-is-not-logged-in