# How to forward request and response on a link click

Tags: jsp, session, servlets, authentication, httpsession

I have a web application. The user will log in and will be presented with a Mainpage. The mainpage is a servlet thus created by a out.println() method. I have a link which when clicked by the user will be redirected to another page say products. But when the user reaches the products page the logged in details is not transfers to products page, as the page has been called by a link. How can i forward the request and response so as to maintain the log in details?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In other words, you didn't store the logged-in user in the HTTP session? Why not? This has got nothing to do with the way how you produced HTML output and that the new request is initiated by a link.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't get you, because this is my first web application im totally struck and i donno what to do. please help me.

Comment: Is this acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274279/filter-and-servlet-for-login/

Comment: Oups. I can understand that you are a true beginner : *The mainpage is a servlet thus created by a out.println() method*, *the logged in details is not transfers to products page, as the page has been called by a link*. You should first try to follow some tutorial on JSP + Servlet + Session. You can find examples at http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/Introduction.aspx and particurlay [Full login example](http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/Full%20Login%20Example.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Though its not a good practice but you can post login parameters to Product page if you don't want to handle through http sessions