# Restrict url redirection without login into website in Java JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I am making a demo login-logout page, it is working fine.

Now I have applied **Filter** in java to restrict user from direct redirection by changing in url.

**Here**, the logic is/(**or what I intended**) is if in session emailId is not found, then send user to login page, otherwise (emailId found in session) proceed with request.

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter, Serializable {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        try {
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            System.out.println("Email = "+session.getAttribute("useremail"));
            if (session.getAttribute("useremail") == null) {
                res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <display-name>Assignment1-LoginLogout</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
  
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            45
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
  
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

**Now**, when I hit this URL in chrome it shows,
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

So i googled it got to know that problem is some recursive call or url pattern is wrong **/***, i tried changing both but none worked.

I am hitting this url in my web browser

http://localhost:8080/Assignment1-LoginLogout/login.jsp

And my project structure if required is

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

And can some one explain me how

**res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp"); vs chain.doFilter(request, response);** differ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, mistake was in LoginFilter class, as I was checking all the url's in web.xml

```
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

So my first page login.jsp was getting called recursively.

So here is the correct version of code.

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter, Serializable {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        try {
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            String loginURL = req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";
            boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("useremail") != null;
            boolean loginRequest = loginURL.equals(req.getRequestURI());
            
            if (loggedIn || loginRequest) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                res.sendRedirect(loginURL);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I found help from here,

[Authentication filter and servlet for login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274279/authentication-filter-and-servlet-for-login/)

Thanks!