# How to correctly replace HttpServletRequest.login function

Tags: java, authentication, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I am getting into Servlets and I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276996) to create my own version of login but I keep getting an error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

login form looks a bit like this:

```
<h:form>
        <p:inputText value="#{loginHandler.username}" id="username" required="true" />
        <p:password value="#{loginHandler.password}" id="password" required="true" />
        <p:commandButton value="Login" actionListener="#{loginHandler.logIn}" />
</h:form>
```

LoginHandler has the logIn func which gets the servlet request and calls the login func

```
 HttpServletRequest req = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
  req.login(username, password);
```

This is part of the login servlet I have set up - I'm just showing the sysout :

```
 @WebServlet("/")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

@EJB private OBJECT objService;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DOGET LOGINSERVLET");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("DOPOST LOGINSERVLET");
    
}

}
```

and this is the LoginFilter:

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
    System.out.println("DOFILTER LOGINFILTER");
    // MORE CODE
   
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("INIT LOGINFILTER");
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("DESTROY LOGINFILTER");
}

}
```

The problem I have is when the user clicks the login button, I get this non descriptive error:

```
 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-3) javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed: javax.el.ELException: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:159)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:237)

Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.login(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:498)


11:14:59,633 ERROR [com.ecm.calt.jsf.errorhandling.CustomExceptionHandler] (default task-3) An unhandled problem has occured. javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:66)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.ecm.calt.jsf.action.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:37)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
```

It does not seem to hit the dopost sysout in the Login Servlet but it hits the doget, it also hits all the functions in the Login filter. What is the disconnect?